# How can I change the icon for a binary file on my desktop?

Tags: 12.04, files, icons, .desktop

I want to change icon of a binary file which is placed on my desktop. The binary file is related to unetbootin. I want to execute unetbootin from the desktop so I want to change the icon.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be talking about a .desktop file? open it with gedit, find the `Icon=` line and change the icon to what you want it to be.

Or, the GUI way: right click on the .desktop file > properties > click on the icon and browse to another icon.

By the way, you need to make it executable to have it work from the desktop!

Comment: where i can find .desktop file?

Comment: @Farooq Aha, I see, I thought you already had it on your desktop. If not, go to `/usr/share/applications` practically every application is represented there by a .desktop file. search for the Unetbootin file and copy it to your desktop (right click > copy, on your desktop right click > paste). Then make it executable and do as described in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

### How to change the icon of a **Unity Launcher** (12.04 or above):

**Unity Launchers** are files stored in your computer, with a `.desktop` extension. These files are used to launch a specific application, but in Unity they are also used so as to create right-click menus for each application, which you can access from the Unity Launcher.

Such file looks something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/home/$USER/Documents/exec.sh
Icon=/home/$USER/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Icon field is the icon that should be used by the launcher and represents the application. All icons that are under the directory `/usr/share/pixmaps` don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension.

For example, if the icon file is `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`, then the Icon field should be just `wallch`. All other icons should have their full path specified.

---

Therefore, in order to change the icon for a specific program, you need to:

**1.** **Find** the related `.desktop` file, they are commonly under `/usr/share/...`.

You can do so with:

```
locate program_name.desktop
```

or if you can't seem to find it:

```
locate *.desktop
```

and scroll through the list.

**2.** **Open** the `.desktop` you want to modify:

```
gedit /path/to/program_name.desktop
```

**3.** **Modify** any of the fields you wish:

Just to be save, make a backup first, which you can replace for the original file in case you screw up:

```
cp /path/to/program_name.desktop /path/to/program_name_backup
```

---

**Source and further information:**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles